# std::initializer_list of variant with values of same type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, metaprogramming

I was trying to remove some redundant code from one of my personal projects and got an idea to dynamically create some properties, so the code is the following

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <variant>

struct t {
  void i(int) {}
  void s(std::string) {}
  void b(bool) {}
};

int main() {
  using setters = std::variant<std::function<void(t *, int)>,
                               std::function<void(t *, std::string)>,
                               std::function<void(t *, bool)>>;
  std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char *, setters>> props{
      {"first", std::function<void(t*, int)>(&t::i)}, {"second", &t::i}};
  int i = 0;
  for(auto& p : props) {
      if (std::get<std::function<void(t*, int)>>(p.second))
         i += 2;
  }
  return i;
}
```

this actually fails to compile but if I replace `&t::i` with `&t::s` for `second` it actually compiles fine and also if I implicitly specify the type of `second` it compiles fine also, but I don't like to specify types everywhere, so is there any way to fix it and also it will not compile if I remove the type of `first`, so is there any way to remove the type specification of first as well
Here is the godbolt link if anyone wants
https://godbolt.org/z/GSb8CL

Comment: The problem here is overload resolution failure between the two methods that take an `int` and `bool` parameters. Since ints and bools can be implicitly converted with each other, a callable object that takes an `int` parameter can be used to initialize a `std::function` that takes a `bool` parameter, and vice versa. So, getting rid of one of them will allow you to do this. It's also possible to throw some cruft in here that will work around implicit type conversions, but that's not going to really answer this question.

Comment: yeap you're correct, now it compiles but i kinda need bool though

Comment: Why do you use `std::function` in such code? Can't you use a variant of member functions of `t` instead? `std::function` is very general and applicable for many cases - but do you really need that?

Comment: Like I said, it's possible to throw some cruft in here that will have the effect of making it possible to call either one, but this will have other implications.

Comment: @ALX23z thanks man I was able to do it by replacing std::functions with decltype(&t::i) decltype(&t::s), thanks again, also thanks Sam Varshavchik for the help